# Login process in symfony2 without FosUserBundle

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working on a symfony2 application and I want to create a security session and role without using FOSUserBundle.

example :

```
class AuthentificationController extends Controller {

    //login
    public function logincheck(Request $req) {
    // ----code 
    //
    //--> create a user session 
    }
}
```

// in twig

```
<!-- here verification : if user is connected see user-space 
                         else redirect 
-->
<!-- admin space -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In symfony docs there is an example of how to create [authenticationProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-providers) and how to [check user for valid session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html)